# CiviEvent & Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I formerly used CiviCRM with a Drupal website and recently moved over to the same Civi install on a Wordpress website. The CiviDB is the same, but the CMS has changed.

Previously, when using CiviEvent, there was a dropdown calendar for selecting the time. Also, when choosing the event location, I could select a formerly used event and it would auto-populate the fields with the event data from that previous event.

Now, on Wordpress, those functions do not work. I have to manually enter the time and date, and while I can select a previously used event, it does not auto-populate the fields (I have to manually re-enter the info, and it will erase any fields that are left blank in the other events that share the location).

My question is whether this is a limitation of the Wordpress version of CiviCRM, or if something was messed up when moving from Drupal to Wordpress. Do other Civi/WP users have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem on your site specifically.

You can always verify this by checking the [public CiviCRM/WP demo site](https://civicrm.org/demo).

To me this sounds like a general javascript error on your site, likely caused by a bad WP plugin or theme. Check the [javascript troubleshooting guide](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35850.0) for more details.

Comment: Yes, the demo site works as I would expect it to. It must be something on my site then... Yuck. Gonna be hard to figure this out...

Comment: Try switching to a basic theme and see if the problem continues. I have seen similar issues that are usually related to the theme.

Comment: Disabling Jetpack fixed this problem for me.